# cloudformation yaml keeps getting invalid principal format

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a KMS key using `cloudformation` but I keep getting an error saying principal is the incorrect format.

What did I do wrong?

```
  # KMS S3 Config Service encryption key
  snsconfigKey:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Key
    Properties:
      KeyPolicy:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Id: key-snsconfig
        Statement:
          - Sid: Enable IAM User Permissions
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Join
                - ''
                - - 'arn:aws-us-gov:iam::'
                  - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                  - ':user/Bob'

            Action: 'kms:*'
            Resource: '*'
  snsconfigKeyAlias:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Alias
    Properties:
      AliasName: alias/snsconfig
      TargetKeyId:
        Ref: snsconfigKey
```

Comment: Does user `user/Bob` actual exist? You can't use non-existing principles in policies.

Comment: Yes, user exist in a format of firstname.lastname

Comment: Can you please then add the region and check. [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/using-govcloud-arns.html#using-govcloud-arn-syntax-iam) show that for `aws-us-gov` region should be provided.

Comment: How did it go? Did you manage to try?